# Host provider for website built using Angular 5 + Web Api 2 + Sql Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, angular, asp.net-web-api, hosting

I have build an web app  using

- Angular 5  => front End
- Microsoft Asp.Net Web API 2 => Middle layer
- SQL server 2016 => data storage

Where I can host ( I am interested to know about host provider, as I do know how to do it on my local box) my website with the above technology stack.
Any help would be appreciated.

**PS:** This question might looks easy but,  trust me, Internet does not have a clear answer of it. There is so much scattered information that it confuses than giving an answer.  I have hosted an static angular web site earlier using AWS. but this time I have real website with API's and Data storage ( Sql server).

Comment: why negative vote? please explain.

Comment: *"why negative vote? please explain"* i didn't downvote but basically *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow "* And also this question is not about "programming" but to find a location where you can host..

Comment: To answer you question more or less.. Hire a VPS (with Windows Server) somewhere and install your environment.. Or use a Linux server with [mono](https://www.mono-project.com/) to run `.NET`  applications or [Linux Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x)

Comment: @Raymond Nijland,  I agree. But I think, I might not have put my question correctly. Just edited it.   The reason for asking this question is - There may be developer who has hosted their own website with similar technology stack. I need their little help here. As Internet did not give the answer.

Comment: *"There may be developer who has hosted their own website with similar technology stack"* pretty sure they also are using a VPS or dedicated machine..As webhosting providers tends to running behide on application updates on `.NET` or SQL Server

Comment: @Raymond Nijland: Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go for Azure VPS to run the same. as it's .Net technology and SQL server you will get SQL as service and Windows Server in VPS. This is just my personal view to go for Azure based upon my hosting experience.

Comment: why negative vote? I just suggested Azure is good than AWS for windows and specially with SQL

Comment: Probably because you have answered a post that is asking us to recommend an off-site resource, *which is off-topic for Stack Overflow*, by recommending an off-site resource.

Comment: @Ketan Kotak: Thanks Ketan for the response.  I am even considering Azure. I will update once I am done hosting my website. An up vote to you.

Comment: Thanks.. I had managed AWS, Azure, our own data center and shared hosting but SQL as service gives best output in terms of performance in Azure. We had purchased unmanaged VPS from Microsoft and a separate support team working over it.